# Окно блокировки экрана

Tags: jquery, javascript

Собственно вопрос: не знаю я, как сделать такое самому, и я без понятия, что искать в гугле для того, чтобы понять как такое делать, по этому спрашиваю у вас, дорогое сообщество!

Скрин прилагается: 
[image]

Как сделать, что бы оно сохраняло набранные кружки, и при следующем наборе, что бы оно только после ихнего ввода пускало в прогу?

Comment: мне в такую прогу было бы лень заходить

Comment: тут ситуация другая) тут придется заходить, а делаю я это из за мер безопасности информации которая будет нести в себе программа.

Comment: подобный ввод ассоциируется с каптчёй, а каптча ассоциируется с негативными эмоциями, к тому же подоный "пароль" легче запомнит тот, кто увидит вводимый мной "путь", что не скажешь про классический __\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*__

Comment: так просит заказчик, я противоречить ему не буду

Comment: Еще варианты и предложения будут? Может хотя бы что искать посоветуете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда-то баловался над не стандартной авторизацией и
[остался примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/sFPG8/1/), не совсем доведённый до ума.
Не уверен, что это именно то, что вам надо, к тому же, не знаю, как это
будет работать на мобильных устройствах. Хотя, может и пригодится.
В примере, можно сделать изменения, приближенные к вашим условиям,
а именно, сделать кнопки не кликабельными, а подключить, к примеру, [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/).

P.S. И естественно, что на jsFiddle с БД не поработаешь, поэтому использовал "БД-заменитель" - localstorage ))

Comment: ооо, хороший пример =) Спасибо, буду думать что с этим можно сделать.

Comment: Если со всякими перетаскиваниями, то [можно как-то так](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/sFPG8/2/). В общем, для извращений - тут непочатый край работы )))

Comment: Немного не те перетаскивания) За ним должно тянуться палочка как на картинке, которая запоминает нужные координаты, ну в общем да, работы начать и кончить (: Спасибо за помощь!!!

Answer (score 1):

Могу только поделится таким вариантом.

[Блокировка экрана](http://depositfiles.com/files/wtgcdmgtr?redirect)

Comment: хммм... спасибо, уже хоть что то (:

Answer (score 1):

[javascript 9-dot Pattern Lock](http://9dotpatternlock.codeplex.com/) - вот, что мне нужно, может кому нибудь пригодится.